# filter ignore lines in a big text file

Tags: text-processing, filenames

i generated a big text file `input.txt`, the content is lines of file paths, which i will use later in a loop
but there're some path patterns i want to remove, like `node_modules`

i have the ignore patterns saved in `ignore.txt` file, how can i filter a `input.txt` file according to `ignore.txt` file to generate `output.txt` file, with all path patterns removed?

thank you!

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036 which might be what you wanted, but that question is also a FAQ in here so there might be some answers laying around this site.

Comment: How did you generate your file? It seems as if the file is unimportant if you can generate the list and ignore those directories while doing so. Somewhat like what's happening here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638960

Answer (score 1):

i guess my question was too vague, i googled around and found it can be done like this:

```
grep -vf ignore.txt input.txt > output.txt
```

ignore.txt:

```
test/
tests/
_test.
/node_modules/
```

`input.txt` was generated by `find`, every line is a file path, it's very large

`output.txt` is in same format/content as input.txt, with paths in ignore.txt patterns removed

Comment: Note that your pattern `_test.` would also filter out lines containing `_test_` (and `_test/`, and `_test-` etc.), so the pattern `_test_` is not needed.