# See if any files of a given extension exist within folder structure, excluding a few directories

Tags: shell, find

I'm trying to put a script together that i can use in my CI build that will work as a linter for my Typescript Mono-repo project.

What I'm trying to accomplish is see if there are any `.js` files within the project/package repos, but avoid `node_modules` folders where ever they are located and also the `common` folder and all its subdirectories and files.

The file structure is like this

```
project/
├── apps/
│   ├── app1
├── common/
│   ├── folder1
│   ├── folder1
│   ├── etc
├── lib/
│   ├── lib1
├── services/
│   ├── service1
```

With the sub-directories of `services,lib,apps` all being npm projects.

Currently some of the different attempts I've tried include:

`find .  \( ! -name node_modules \) -o \( ! -path common -prune \)  -name "*.js" -print`

But it doesn't seem to return anything even when I create dummy `.js` files in `/project` or any of the other whitelisted folders.

This attempt seems to be the closest as it prints out the test files, but it also finds files within `common`, but it should be blacklisted.

`find . -type d \( -path common -o -name node_modules \) -prune -false -o -name '*.js'`

The output of that run:

```
./test.js
./common/temp/pnpmfile.js
./common/temp/pnpm-store/2/registry.npmjs.org/ipaddr.js
./common/config/rush/pnpmfile.js
./common/scripts/install-run.js
./common/scripts/install-run-rushx.js
./common/scripts/install-run-rush.js
./services/test.js
```

The overall goal I want from this script is to, exit 0 if no `.js` files are found within the whitelisted directories or return exit 1 if a `.js` file is found outside of the blacklisted directories.

I'm pretty new and inexperienced with shell commands, so any help would be appreciated Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your command is almost correct.  Fixing it:

```bsh
find . \( -name node_modules -o -path ./common \) -prune -o -name '*.js' -print
```

This prunes anything called `node_modules` or that is located at `./common`. Note that the pathname used with `-path` is a path with the top-level search path as start, and therefore must start with `.` in this case.

The `-false` that you use is not needed.  It would be needed if either `node_modules` or `./common` had also matched your `-name` test after `-o`.  This is also when you may have wanted to use `-type d`, which you now don't have to do.

Testing:

```
$ tree
.
|-- common
|   `-- file.js
|-- dir
|   |-- common
|   |   `-- file.js
|   |-- file.js
|   `-- node_modules
|       `-- file.js
`-- node_modules
    `-- file.js

5 directories, 5 files
```

```
$ find . \( -name node_modules -o -path ./common \) -prune -o -name '*.js' -print
./dir/file.js
./dir/common/file.js
```

The file `./dir/common/file.js` is found since it lives in a non-pruned directory (`common` is only pruned if it is directly below the current directory).

---

[Elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638998/116858), it seems that all you want to do is to see if there are *any* files matching `*.js` in the non-pruned directories.  You can do this efficiently with

```bsh
if find . \( -name node_modules -o -path ./common \) -prune -o -name '*.js' -exec echo . \; | grep -q .
then
    echo there are JS files
else
    echo there are no JS files
fi
```

Here, I output a single dot (could be any character) whenever I find a file, and I use `grep -q .` to detect any output from `find`.  When something is found, `grep` would terminate with a zero exit-status, signalling "success", and the `if` statement would take the first branch.  The `find` command would terminate as soon as it tried to write another dot to the pipe that `grep` no longer is listening to.

Answer (score 0):

If you use -path use a fully declared path like `./common` or use `-name` to match anywhere in your found tree.

This command worked for me as a test.

```bsh
find . -type d \( -name common -o -name node_modules \) -prune -false -o -name '*.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

The command I ended up going with after reviewing and testing some of the above answers is this:

```
find . \( -name node_modules -o -path ./common \) -prune -o -name '*.js' -print
```

And the reason I had to keep the `-print` arg is that I found the output I got when running it without `-print` was showing some of the folders as output like this:

```
./common
./lib/trader-sdk/node_modules
./lib/is-ticker-symbol/node_modules
./apps/cron-app/node_modules
./services/templating-service/node_modules
./services/api-service/node_modules
./services/trading-services/node_modules
./services/sentiment-service/node_modules
```

But when I tacked on the `-print` arg the output was nothing, which is what was expected in this situation.

Bonus: This is the final use case, a basic script that will check my TypeScript mono-repo to ensure that no-one is trying to merge any build `.js` files into master.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

jsFiles=$(find . \( -name node_modules -o -path ./common \) -prune -o -name '*.js' -print)

if [ -z "$jsFiles" ]
then
      echo "No JS files found, free to proceed"
      exit 0
else
      echo "JS files found, unable to proceed"
      exit 1
fi
```